# DataGridView stops working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Probably (and hopefully) this is a very easy question, but yet I haven't been able to find an answer to it.

I am working on a Windows Forms application. I have created a database containing three tables. In the design mode I inserted a datagridview, chose which table I wanted to display and when I run the application all the stored data is shown in the grid, just like I want.

My problem is that whenever I touch the dataset or the database the connection to the datagridview stops working, it doesn't load any data. Even something as simple as doubleclicking on the data.sdf in the solution explorer makes the connection go away, the datagrid becomes empty.

And when the connection once have been broken I can never get it back in the same project so I have to go back to an old "not infected" version that I have saved.

I can't seem to find anything that has been changed in the code when I compare my old working version and the not working. I read through the DataSet code, the xsd-file, checked the settings for the datagrid but nothing. It looks exaclty alike from what I can see.

This wouldn't be that much of a problem if it weren't that I would like to edit one of the tables (not the one connected to the grid) and add an nvarchar that I forgot. But if I change anything, the connection is lost.

My question is therefor; exactly what part of the connection to the datagridview gets broken whenever I change anything in the database? And how do I do to fix this?

**Short summary**

I have a database. I added a datagridview via drag and drop and it displays the content from a table. It works perfectly.

But the connection stops working and the grid becomes empty whenever I:

1. Doubleclick the database file in the explorer to display its content
2. Drop/Add/Edit any table in the database
3. Run the DataSet Wizard again to include/exclude tables
4. Press "Refresh" on the database, its tables or the dataset

What gets broken by doing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is there any possibility to use Linq-to-sql or entity framework...because it gives more flexibility rather than using datasets in winfroms ...

Comment: I suppose it is possible (even though I have never heard of it), it is just this is a very simple and easy way of getting started with programming and databases (I am pretty new to this). Therefor it would be great if I could continue use Windows Forms. I just wonder if anyone knows what part of the connection that might get broken by doing what I wrote and if there is an easy fix.

I feel like I have enough to learn anyways as it is right now before  starting to use another framework and such, but thank you anyways.

Comment: You can use Windows Forms with EF, Linq2Sql or most other OR-Mappers out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept on struggling, trying to experiment what files that actually caused it to stop working.
After a while I found out that the difference between working or not was the database file itself. If I switched back to an old one, it started to work.

I don't really remember how I got to this conclusion but finally I realised that the only possible reason was that debug version of the database and the actual project version weren't "in sync". Don't ask me why or how, but after I deleted both the files and replaced them with the same file, all the problems went away. I can change tables and it never ever looses the connection.

From what I understand, this has to be some type of bug in Vegas. Doing clean rebuilds did nothing but after manually deleting and replacing files, it started to work again.